# Is there a place for questions that don't really rise to the level of a full SO question?

Tags: discussion

I've been around long enough to realize that some questions are not really suitable for a full SO treatment, and asking them will only get you downvoted.

For example, this question.  In C#, what exactly is being created by the following statement:

```
public List<List<string>> LineData = new List<List<string>>();
```

I know it's a "list of lists", but all I want to know is what the "()" on the end means.

But if I posted that as a question, it would immediately get me about 5 downvotes.  Why?  I do not know.  Probably because the answer to this question doesn't actually solve any problem.

So, is there a place where SIMPLE questions can be asked that don't need a full voting experience, and can be answered casually in comments alone, without risking downvotes?

There are some of here who come to LEARN, and learning sometimes isn't about solving a problem.  Sometimes it's just asking for an explanation.

Comment: You could try chat?

Comment: There is such a thing?  Where is this manna from heaven?  ;-)

Comment: Simple questions don't get downvoted because they're simple. They get downvoted because they're simple enough that either 1) the answer can easily be found in the documentation, or 2) they've probably already been asked and answered before. A simple question *can* be a full-fledged SO question if the answer really cannot be found in any readily available documentation, *and* no one remembers it having been asked before.

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace Down, down, down, in the inky blackness of the site footer, where armies of `<a>`s rule the land. Some even say, wandering about in a full moon, that you can find a `<blink>`...

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) _might_ be an ok place, be sure to look for a room that's about that topic, and read any rules they have posted. (Side note: the `()` specifies that the compiler should use the 0 argument `List` constructor. It's _essentially_ a function call.)

Comment: @BoltClock:  Thanks.  That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thanks, @theB.  Appreciate the insight.

Comment: Simple questions can often also be perfectly valid if you actually show *what* you researched, since that at least helps to show where the knowledge gap is. Effectively, you should be trying to make your question clear, show research effort, and be potentially useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "SO level" for questions - any question related to coding can be on-topic irrespective how simple it is.

Some questions will be downvoted so - often for lack of *demonstrated* research - (see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for guidance). For sample you've shown I personally don't believe there is a way to demonstrate research for basic "what this language construct means" for language that is out there for 10-15 years with publicly available specifications and documentation (like C/C++/Java/C#/JavaScript...). It is pretty much guaranteed that answer is either in first pages of "Getting Stared..." article or some existing questions on SO. Same question may be perfectly fine for brand new language without much documentation.

You can see that pattern even for C# - there are usually waves of well received "what this .... syntax" mean around new releases of C# (like "what does `??` mean") and than later same type of question will get downvotes as information is readily available.

Comment: Thanks.  That DOES help me understand why sometimes a question get's upvoted, but then some other question, asking almost the same thing, gets downvoted.  SO is obviously very thorough.  Thanks.